# CSS: `min-height: min-content` doesn't work with `flex-row`

Tags: css, flexbox

When the height of the parent flex element is set to less than the min-height, the expected result should be for the element to expand to contain its content. This works with `flex-direction:row` and `min-width: min-content`, but using literally the same code but with `column` instead of `row` and `min-height` instead of `min-width` doesn't cause the parent element to expand but instead retain its original height and clipping its' children.

```css
.flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
  height : 200px;
    border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; border-color: black;
  
  
/*  Width is set to 100px but because the min-content is 600px, the width overridden.  */
    min-width: min-content;
  width: 100px; 
}
.block-row{
    align-self: stretch;
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}


/* Literally same code except flex-col and min-height */

.flex-col{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    min-height: min-content;
    border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; border-color: black;
}
.block-col{
    align-self: stretch;
    background-color: red;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>min-content :(</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  
Intended effect works with flex-row min-width  
   <div class="flex-row" style="width: 100px; height : 200px; ">
            <div class="block-row"></div>
            <div class="block-row"></div>
        </div>
  </br>
  Doesn't work with same code except min-height  :( 
  
  </br>
  -> Height is set to 100px, but instead of min-height of children causing height to grow, it is stuck at 100px for some reason.

</br> 
      <div class="flex-col" style="height: 100px; width : 200px; ">
            <div class="block-col"></div>
            <div class="block-col"></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using px use vh that allow you to use the relavite space in the container